# PBS: Check contents of submitted job file

Tags: pbs

Is there a way to check the contents of a submitted job script/file (job can be queued/running)? Basically, I want to be able to see the commands inside my script file.

Answer (score 1):

To see the file that TORQUE has saved for the job, you'll need to have root access. The file is located in TORQUE_HOME/server_priv/jobs/JOBID.SC. Most of the time, TORQUE is installed to /var/spool/torque, making that the value for TORQUE_HOME. For example, the script file for job 1.host could be viewed:

```
vi /var/spool/torque/server_priv/jobs/1.host.SC
```

Comment: So there is no way for user (non-admin) to view even for his own jobs?

Comment: I don't think there's any way other than keeping a copy of the script that you submitted.